# How can I tell from a Wicket Page object that it has changed?

Tags: wicket, wicket-tester

Here's my scenario. I'm testing a Wicket app, and I'm parsing the page text `wicktetTester.getServletResponse.getDocument` as XML in order to find components with XPath. This is quite expensive, so I'd like to keep the `dom4j.Document` until the page changes, then rebuild it.

I know the current page - `wicketTester.getLastRenderedPage` but if I for example submit a form and stay on the same page, the `Page` object is the same object. What property of the page can I query to know that it has been re-rendered and that I need to rebuild my DOM?

```
public Document getDocument() {
   if (tester.getLastRenderedPage() != lastPageParsed && SOME_OTHER_TEST) {
       cachedDocument = parse(tester.getServletResponse().getDocument();
       lastPageParsed = tester.getLastRenderedPage();
   }
   return cachedDocument;
}
```

Comment: _but if I for example submit a form and stay on the same page, the Page object does not change_ Generally this isn't true. When you submit a form, the current page is re-rendered. Whether the result is the same HTML output or not depends on your page.

Comment: Depends on your definition of change - the object identity or state - I've clarified the question - the `Page` remains the same object, but its state changes. I want to know if the state is different without re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Better see TagTester. I guess it will serve you better than XPath.

Comment: I wish it did, but I can't see how. It isn't checking the tags that's the problem - its finding them. My GUI has a form with a table where a column may contain multiple checkboxes. The id-paths to find a component just get crazy - `order-panel:form:table:body:rows:1:cells:18:cell:listview:0:site-checkbox:checkbox`. With XPath I can use for example `//(input[@type="checkbox"])[3]` to get the third checkbox on the page.